# how to setup dns nameserver in docker permanently in user-defined network?

Tags: networking, docker, dns, nameservers

I need define nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf user defined network.

I know that directive --dns is working in default bridge of docker engine.

But I created user defined network.

Answer (score 1):

There are two documentation pages describing the different modes

for the bridge mode:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/

for the user defined network:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/

The documentation for user defined network states:
*The exact details of how Docker manages the DNS configurations inside the container can change from one Docker version to the next. So you should not assume the way the files such as /etc/hosts, /etc/resolv.conf are managed inside the containers and leave the files alone and use the following Docker options instead.*

If you now look at the details of the documentation you'll find out that
--dns will also work in the user defined network mode but that there are more options available and certain default behavior applies.